# Why did Java 8 introduce *Integer.sum(int a, int b)*

Tags: java, integer, java-8

I just noticed that JDK8 introduced this method for `Integer` class:

```
 /**
 * Adds two integers together as per the + operator.
 *
 * @param a the first operand
 * @param b the second operand
 * @return the sum of {@code a} and {@code b}
 * @see java.util.function.BinaryOperator
 * @since 1.8
 */
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

What's the point of this method? Why should i call this method instead of using the `+` operator? The only possibility I can think of is that, for instance, when mixing strings and ints the `+` operator changes meaning, so

```
System.out.println("1"+2+3); // prints 123
System.out.println("1"+Integer.sum(2,3)); // prints 15
```

but using parenthesis would work anyway

```
System.out.println("1"+(2+3)); // prints 15
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It can be useful as a method reference (`Integer::sum`) passed to a method that requires a relevant functional interface (`IntBinaryOperator`).

For example :

```
int sum = IntStream.range(1,500).reduce(0,Integer::sum);
```

Of course, this example can use `.sum()` instead of reduce. I just noticed that the Javadoc for [IntStream.sum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) mention this exact reduction as being equivalent to sum().

Comment: Uhm... that's probably something I'm yet to study.

Comment: Same. I've never seen the use of this.

Comment: The far more interesting question is: What about `difference`, `product` and `quotient`? (Maybe not enough "obvious" use-cases for this. But whether one uses `Integer::sum` or `(a,b)->(a+b)` doesn't matter so much either...)

Comment: @Marco13 yeah, I was wondering the same thing, did you find out why they omitted difference, product and quotient? I think difference and quotient aren't very necessary, because their semantics are arguable, but product is clearly defined.

Comment: @POrekhov I don't see an obvious reason. I agree that `difference` and `quotient` may be questionable (particularly `quotient`, due to the divide-by-zero issue). But `product` could have been included. The only reason for omitting it that I can imagine is that it is more prone to overflows than `sum`, but that's not really a profound, technical reason.