# Use plus operator of integer as BiFunction

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map in which I want to count things. Previous to java 8, I would have had to put a zero in the map for every key, before I could so something like `map.put(key, map.get(key)+1)`.

Since Java 8, I can now use [Map's merge method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) like in the following example:

```
public class CountingMap {

  private static final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<> ();

  public static Integer add (final Integer i1,
                             final Integer i2) {
    return i1 + i2;
  }

  public static void main (final String[] args) {
    map.merge (0, 1, CountingMap::add);
    System.out.println (map); //prints {0=1}
    map.merge (0, 1, CountingMap::add);
    System.out.println (map); //prints {0=2}
  }

}
```

My question is, can I pass a reference to the + operator of Integer as BiFunction instead of having to declare my own add function?

I already tried things like `Integer::+`, `Integer::operator+`, but none of those works.

**EDIT:** As Tunaki pointed out, I could've used `Integer::sum` instead. Still, I'm wondering whether there is a possibility to pass an operator directly as reference.

Comment: `Integer::sum`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731055/why-did-java-8-introduce-integer-sumint-a-int-b

Comment: I seem to have missed one of the most obvious method names, thanks. Looking at the question you referenced, it seems like there is no possiblity of passing a reference to the + operator directly without such a "helper function".

Comment: To answer your question in the edit: No, there is no way to pass an operator directly as a reference in Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to pass `+` operator in Java.
You can instantiate `add` directly in method call.

```
map.merge (0, 1, (i, j) -> i + j);
```

Or assign variable:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add = (i, j) -> i + j;
```

Or the same things with `Integer::sum`